# Как поделить цифру 1 на другие целые числа

Tags: c++, деление

### Бесконечно малые числа

Привет, мне нужна помощь,
я пытаюсь произвести такое действие 1 / ((2 * n) - 1),
использовал уже:

- *double*
- *float*
- *long*

Но мне всё равно выдаёт 0. Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне делать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не нужно код выставлять картинкой. Оформляйте вопросы правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Написать, например

```
1 / (2.0 * n - 1)
```

Просто поскольку у вас все значения целые - выполняется целочисленное деление, а вам нужно деление с плавающей точкой. То, в какой переменной вы потом сохраняете целочисленный результат - никак не влияет на вычисления...